# Removing Values in DataFrame Based On Condition R

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, maxlength

I have a data frame of 4 columns (magnified for this example). Most columns have outliers which are significantly larger than the other values in the data frame. For example: A column (with a maximum value of 99), has outliers with 96, 97, 98, 99. These outliers signify essentially "no response". This obviously heavily skews the data, thus they must be removed. I want to remove the outliers, but each variable has a different maximum value (and different set of outliers) and some have decimals.

96, 97, 98, 99 must be removed ONLY from the columns that have those as reserve values. So the function must know which columns have each specific classification of reserve values. More below.

The issue is that, I do not want to "remove from all columns" the reserve values as some values may mean something else in another column. For example removing 996 in one column could mean something of significance in another column, such as hourly wage/week.

It get tricky as some have decimals like hours worked/week. For example. 37.5 hours worked per week would have reserve values of 999.6, 999.7, 999.8, 999.9.
This length would be classified as 5.1.

I need to remove these reserve values from the data frame, but they must first match the corresponding reserve value length. Since each column has a different reserve value, the column names of the data frame should correspond to a specific reserve value.

```
df <- data.frame("children#" = c(1,5,0,2,10), 
    "annual income" = c(700000.00,50000.65,30000.45,1000000.59,9999999.96), 
    "hour wage"= c(25.65,9999999.99,50.23,1000.72,65.16), 
    "hours worked/week" = c(148.5,77.0,64.2,25.9,999.7))
```

Max length of children# is 2
Max length of annual income is 10.2 (10 total, 2 decimal)
Max length of hour wage is 10.2
Max length of hours worked/week is 5.1 (5 total, 1 decimal)

ALWAYS WILL BE 4 RESERVE VALUES
If max length = 2, remove reserve values: 96,97,98,99
If max length = 3, remove reserve values: 996, 997, 998, 999... and so forth with solid numbers

With decimals:
If max length = 5.1, remove reserve values: 999.6, 999.7, 999.8, 999.9.
If max length = 10.2, remove reserve values: 9999999.96, 9999999.97, 9999999.98, 9999999.99

Thus, I would like to figure out how to make a function that will

1. **find max lengths**
2. **connect the corresponding max lengths with the correct reserve values**
3. **remove reserve values from data frame based on max lengths of each column**

So far I have the max lengths of each column with the decimal points.

I just need some help with connecting it to the reserve values and getting those reserve values removed from the data frame.

If more info is required please comment as I will elaborate further if needed.

Code sample: For the reserve values I was thinking of creating a separate data frame and using that to remove the values. Other suggestions are welcome.

```
Find.Max.Length <- function(data){
# Check Max Length of each column
tmp <- data.frame(lapply(data, function(x) max(nchar(x, keepNA = F))))
tmp <- data.frame(t(tmp))
return(tmp)}
max.length <- Find.Max.Length(df)

Check.Decimal.Places <- function(x){
if((x %% 1) != 0){
nchar(strsplit(sub('0+$', '',as.character(x)), ".", fixed = TRUE)[[1]][[2]])
}else{
return(0)}
}

decimal <- data.frame(Check.Decimal.Places(df$random)) #<--- used to 
initialize the variable before the loop

for(i in seq_along(df)){
decimal[i] <- data.frame(Check.Decimal.Places(df[[i]]))}

decimal<- data.frame(t(decimal))
rownames(decimal) <- names(df)
length.df <- cbind(max.length, decimal)
names(length.df) <- c("Max Length", "Decimal Place")

length.df$NewVariableLength <- paste0(length.df$`Max Length`, sep= 
".",length.df$`Decimal Place`)
```

NOTE: Row names of length.df data frame match original data frame names. That can possibly be a way to link the two together?

There is probably a faster way to do this all, all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: isn't "max length" of `hours.worked.week` 5 ?

Comment: It is actually 5.1, I have made the edits. Since a decimal place is present in the variable, there must be a decimal in the max length. This is meant to decipher from the variables that have a max length of 5 and do not contain a decimal place. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: It does not seem like a robust approach.

1. Is there any way you know, without looking at the data, which column has which maximum value / number of digits ("max length")?

2. Do you **always** have four outliers in each column? If yes, you could remove just the highest four values.

Comment: Thank you for the response. 1. Unfortunately, there is no way other than just finding the max lengths. Since there are decimal places, it make it rather difficult. 2. Yes, there are always 4 outlier values for each max length. The issue with doing that is that the 4 outliers are the reserve values of a survey (96,97,98,99). If you remove the top 4 outliers and the data only has 3 reserve values, then you are removing 1 important outlier. Thus, the function must know to remove only those 4 values and not any other important outliers. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I edited my answer. I am still not convinced that a "maximum length" approach makes sense. What if, by accident, all answers for a question with maximum length = 3 were only in the range of 1-99 and without "reserved answers"? Then you would have no clear indicator as to what to do with this data.

Comment: @AlexPeters, just by the way: I feel you could use some training in basic techniques on how to work with and/or think about data. I'd really suggest you to do a course, e.g., the "Data Science" track on coursera, to be able to tackle these kinds of tasks more easily on your own.

Answer (score 1):

*edit: Now I understand what you mean with "reserve values" - answers from a survey that should not be counted (e.g. "I don't want to answer this question")*

You have essentially three easy methods here without having to search of "integer length" or other overengineering:

1. **Max values** (i.e., remove the four highest values),
2. **Manual thresholds** (i.e., remove all values above X),
3. **If-else logic** (i.e., if answer == X, remove it).

### Building the dataset

Your data did not correspond to your specifications ("always 4 outliers"), so I took the liberty to extend it.

```r
df <- data.frame(
               "children" = c(1, 0, 96, 2, 10, 99, 98, 99),
               "annual_income" = c(700000.00, 50000.65, 30000.45, 1000000.59, 9999999.96, 9999999.97, 9999999.98, 9999999.99),
               "hour_wage"= c(25.65, 9999999.99, 50.23, 9999999.98, 9999999.99, 9999999.98, 1000.72, 65.16),
               "hours_worked_week" = c(148.5, 999.6, 77.0, 64.2, 999.9, 999.8, 25.9, 999.7)
               )

df
  children annual_income   hour_wage hours_worked_week
1        1     700000.00       25.65             148.5
2        0      50000.65  9999999.99             999.6
3       96      30000.45       50.23              77.0
4        2    1000000.59  9999999.98              64.2
5       10    9999999.96  9999999.99             999.9
6       99    9999999.97  9999999.98             999.8
7       98    9999999.98     1000.72              25.9
8       99    9999999.99       65.16             999.7
```

### <del>1. Maximum-Values-Approach</del> (obsolete after clarification)

Load libraries

```r
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
```

Get the four outliers

```r
children_out <- tail(sort(df$children), 4)
```

Replace outliers with NA

```r
df[df$children %in% children_out,]
    %<>% mutate(children = NA)
```

Check dataset

```r
df
  children annual_income   hour_wage hours_worked_week
1        1     700000.00       25.65             148.5
2        0      50000.65  9999999.99             999.6
3       NA      30000.45       50.23              77.0
4        2    1000000.59  9999999.98              64.2
5       10    9999999.96  9999999.99             999.9
6       NA    9999999.97  9999999.98             999.8
7       NA    9999999.98     1000.72              25.9
8       NA    9999999.99       65.16             999.7
```

Caveat: This approach will work **only if you always have four outliers for each column**.

### 2. Manual thresholds

Load libraries

```r
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
```

Exclude existing NA and replace anything that is 96 or above with NA

```r
df[!is.na(df$children) & df$children >=96, ] %<>%
    mutate(children = NA)
```

Check dataset

```r
df
  children annual_income   hour_wage hours_worked_week
1        1     700000.00       25.65             148.5
2        0      50000.65  9999999.99             999.6
3       NA      30000.45       50.23              77.0
4        2    1000000.59  9999999.98              64.2
5       10    9999999.96  9999999.99             999.9
6       NA    9999999.97  9999999.98             999.8
7       NA    9999999.98     1000.72              25.9
8       NA    9999999.99       65.16             999.7
```

### 3. If-else logic

Load libraries

```r
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
```

Save "reserved answers"

```r
children_res <- c(96, 97, 98, 99)
```

Replace anything that is a reserved answer with NA (excluding existing NA is not needed here)

```r
df[df$children %in% children_res, ] %<>%
    mutate(children = NA)
```

Check dataset

```r
df
  children annual_income   hour_wage hours_worked_week
1        1     700000.00       25.65             148.5
2        0      50000.65  9999999.99             999.6
3       NA      30000.45       50.23              77.0
4        2    1000000.59  9999999.98              64.2
5       10    9999999.96  9999999.99             999.9
6       NA    9999999.97  9999999.98             999.8
7       NA    9999999.98     1000.72              25.9
8       NA    9999999.99       65.16             999.7
```

### 4. edit: Combined approach 1&3

Load libraries

```r
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
```

Get "reserved answers"

```r
children_res <- tail(sort(unique(df$children)), 4)
```

Replace anything that is a reserved answer with NA (excluding existing NA is not needed here)

```r
df[df$children %in% children_res, ] %<>%
    mutate(children = NA)
```

Caveat: This approach will work **only if you always have ALL reserved answers (e.g., 96, 97, 98, and 99) present in each column**. This will **NOT WORK** if, by accident, nobody would answer "97".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, this will not work as some columns have the same outlier value repeated many times. Some columns have 100+ outliers of (96,97,98,& 99). Do you have any suggestions on how to create a function that will know to remove just those 4 values, for example. Also keeping in mind that each column has different reserve values.

Comment: EDIT: I used unique to find the top 4 values and now just need to figure out how to allow the function to only remove the reserve values.

Comment: incorporated it in approach #4